# How important are screenshots in technical documentation?

Tags: documentation, screenshot

All of us have suffered through learning a new task with a new piece of software.

**Examples:**

- Creating a new ASP.NET MVC project
- Creating a new WordPress Plug-in
- Migrating a local MySQL database to a remote server
- Etc.

**The question is:**

- How useful were screenshots in helping us learn?
- Or was a detailed list of steps more helpful for helping us learn?

--

**Additional background:**

This conversation was partially started by [this post](http://idratherbewriting.com/2007/01/27/10-pet-peeves-of-technical-writing):

> Pet Peeve #5. Instructions that have
>   unnecessary screenshots, and
>   instructions that are missing
>   necessary screenshots.
>
> I know this
>   seems a bit of a contradiction, but
>   the writer ought to know when a
>   screenshot is needed and when one
>   isn’t. If the step is confusing, add a
>   screenshot. If it’s a no-brainer,
>   leave it out. If you have a task that
>   is only about 7 steps long, but the
>   writer has included a screenshot every
>   step of the way, it bloats the task
>   and makes it look more arduous than it
>   is. But sometimes every word in the
>   world can’t describe the information
>   conveyed in one screenshot.

And also [this article](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Technical_writing_tools):

> Visuals in technical writing are
>   important. According to "a study on
>   learning using a 94-page manual versus
>   using 25 flash cards....people learned
>   more quickly with the flash cards that
>   covered key ideas and hints, and [not
>   by] step-by-step instruction."
>
> This
>   anecdote from Kim Nathans illustrates
>   most users' reaction to documentation:
>   "I got my first actual feedback from a
>   new employee (Director of Development)
>   and he was disappointed that I didn’t
>   include a pictorial storyboard of the
>   process flow. It turns out that he
>   didn’t so much read any of my
>   documentation as just glance at it.

These 2 articles demonstrate the varying opinions on what constitutes "unnecessary screenshots". Screenshots are time-consuming to create and maintain; thus technical writers hate them. However, users seem to love them and there is evidence that suggests that visual learning is both preferred and more effective.

**So, how important are screenshots in technical writing?**

Answer (score 1):

Like most things in technical communication, how important screenshots are depends on your audience. If you're preparing docs for people who spend all day in a terminal session, they're probably not desperate for that visual flair. But if you're trying to teach to a grandmother who uses a computer only to check her email, those screenshots might be the most important thing in your docs. It hinges on what sort of knowledge and abilities your readers already have and what their expectations for learning are.

So if screenshots aren't important to an audience, they probably shouldn't be important to their technical writer either. But even if they are important, it doesn't necessarily follow that screenshots are worth doing. For example, if you don't have the resources (time, chiefly) to keep screenshots current, they can become a point of confusion for the audience. Choosing to do illustrations (whether it's screenshots or screencasts or line art) isn't just about understanding what your audience desires, but it's also about knowing your own capabilities.

Comment: Your 2 example audiences (grandma & the UNIX admin) show the extremes, but don't help to guide real-world decisions.  Almost all use-cases will fall into the middle of these extremes.  Does that mean most use-cases merit SOME screenshots?

Comment: The short answer is yes. If I'm writing docs for our hypothetical UNIX admin, I might even include a familiarizing screenshot for some visual elements (say, a web interface for some database) so that reader can know if they're seeing what they're supposed to be seeing. But it might be just one.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshots are only important to documentation if they add value to the material. Identifying specific types of readers only helps in developing the depth of your documentation. You would not tell a developer how to use a mouse, in fact they may find it insulting that you suggest they are using a mouse at all!

Having been a professional writer and technologist for nearly 20 years, I can say without equivocation that documentation isn't nearly as complicated as it appears. Write clearly and concisely. Get to the point. Don't yammer on and on about this and that and don't try to be clever. Clever is confusing.

Don't rant on for paragraph after paragraph, either. If you have a valid use for screenshots, you can use them and formatted blockquotes to break up the flow and make reading more interesting. The last thing anyone wants is to have some critical warning buried in a long-winded ramble.

Be consistent and don't involve too much fancy formatting. If you start notating menu selections like so: **Apple > Dock > Position On Left**, you must always format menu selections the same way. It not only helps your reader as they read, but to use your writing as a reference. It's easier to find something important when it stands out.

Color is also important, even more than icons. Color speaks out to the reader and has emotional impact. Red stands out as important, critical, or something to be concerned about. Green gives people a sense of moving forward or making advances. Blue is calming, great for something that's helpful but not critical.

Finally, don't worry so much about being an English major and applying careful rules for writing. Documentation helps people understand what they are doing, and it will not end up on the New York Times Bestseller List or get a Pulitzer. Be natural and conversational. Just don't be too conversational. Knowing your audience will help greatly.